# What is the Python equivalent to R data.table column creation?

Tags: python, r, data.table, py-datatable

I'm in the process of converting my R scripts to python. Is there a similar process in creating new columns that r data.table does in the J step? Below is my example code in R:

```
dat[,Returned_on_time:= ifelse(Contract_End_Date==Estimated_In_Date,'Yes','No')]
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but it can be something like this `df["Returned_on_time"] = np.where(df["Contract_End_Date"] == df["Estimated_In_Date"], 'Yes', 'No')`

Comment: I don't know R and it would be simpler if you would show example data and result for this data.

Comment: that was exactly what i was looking for, just learning the differences in syntax. Thank you!

Comment: other idea: first create new column only with `No` - `df["Returned_on_time"] = "No"` and later assign `Yes` to selected rows `df.loc[ df["Contract_End_Date"] == df["Estimated_In_Date"], "Returned_on_time"] = "Yes"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your R example illustrates `data.table`'s fast in-place generation of your new column.

A python equivalent of in-place creation in the `j` slot is shown below using python `datatable`

```
from datatable import dt,f,update

dat=dt.Frame({"Contract_End_Date":["2022-01-02", "2022-04-15", "2022-12-19"],
              "Estimated_In_Date":["2022-04-26", "2022-04-15", "2022-11-30"]
             })

dat[:, dt.update(Returned_on_time = dt.ifelse(f.Contract_End_Date == f.Estimated_In_Date, "Yes", "No"))]
```

Output:

```
   | Contract_End_Date  Estimated_In_Date  Returned_on_time
   | str32              str32              str32           
-- + -----------------  -----------------  ----------------
 0 | 2022-01-02         2022-04-26         No              
 1 | 2022-04-15         2022-04-15         Yes             
 2 | 2022-12-19         2022-11-30         No              
[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @furas for the fast solution using numpy.

```
df["Returned_on_time"] = np.where(df["Contract_End_Date"] == df["Estimated_In_Date"], 'Yes', 'No')
```